# JIRA copy custom fields in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am aware that JIRA dataset is in beta stage right now in Data factory. But still is there any way to pull the custom fields data?

Right now when i am copying JIRA issues data it is giving me only the standard fields present in any of the Issue.

I want custom fields too. Any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So through hit and trial, i got to know that tables that starts with 'Extras- ' are the ones which has custom fields and that too masked. Again through hit and trial I figured which field value I wanted to extract.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the advanced tab.
For linked service:
[advanced tab for linked service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtePh.png)

For dataset:
[advanced tab for dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z0j2.png)